Workaround GCC bug to create an immediately-accessed automatically-typed vector literal of function pointers
Problem
A known bug in GCC <12 precludes initialising and immediately accessing implicitly typed vectors like so:
auto elem = (std::vector {1, 2, 3})[0];

which for some types, can be worked around using decltype:
auto elem = (std::vector <decltype(1)> {1, 2, 3})[0];

Alas this workaround does not work for function pointers:
void f() { }

// won't compile in Clang nor GCC for unknown (by me) reason
auto elem = (std::vector <decltype(f)> {f,f,f})[0];

// won't compile in GCC due to known bug
auto elem = (std::vector {f, f, f})[0];

Why does this workaround not work for function pointers, despite it working for other types? Is there another workaround such that a vector of function pointers can be initialised and immediately accessed without explicitly declaring the pointer type (i.e. the function signature)?
Further context
Consider creating a vector of elements without explicitly declaring the element type:
auto vec = std::vector{1, 2, 3};

This compiles fine with Clang and GCC (with -std=c++17). I wish however to avoid assigning the vector to a variable, and instead fetch an element in the same line:
auto elem = (std::vector{1, 2, 3}) [0];

This compiles fine in Clang, but fails in GCC with exception
error: missing template arguments after ‘vector<...auto...>’
      |     auto elem = (std::vector{1, 2, 3})[0];
      |                 ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/vector:67,
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:389:11: note: ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’ declared here
      |     class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
      |           ^~~~~~

This is an identical error to that triggered when compiling my original example in a standard earlier than C++17. It is as if GCC fails to recognise the implicit-type syntax if it is a sub-expression. Is this a bug in GCC?
In any case, I can remedy it using decltype:
auto elem = (std::vector <decltype(0)> {1, 2, 3}) [0];

which compiles in both Clang and GCC.
Alas, I do not actually wish to store integers, but function pointers! The below code compiles fine in Clang but fails in GCC, as we saw occur with integers.
void f() {}

auto elem = (std::vector {f, f, f}) [0];

Alas trying to use decltype, which worked for integers, does not work for function pointers! Expression
(std::vector <decltype(f)> {f, f, f}) [0]

will fail to compile in both Clang and GNU, with errors:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:222:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:23:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator.h:151:19: error: multiple overloads of 'address' instantiate to the same signature 'const_pointer (const_reference) const noexcept' (aka 'void (*(void (&)()) const noexcept)()')
    const_pointer address(const_reference __x) const _NOEXCEPT {
                  ^

/usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘class __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<void()>’:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/allocator.h:124:11:   required from ‘class std::allocator<void()>’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:87:21:   required from ‘struct std::_Vector_base<void(), std::allocator<void()> >’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:389:11:   required from ‘class std::vector<void()>’
test.cpp:25:48:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:96:7: error: ‘const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference) const [with _Tp = void(); __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_pointer = void (*)(); __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference = void (&)()]’ cannot be overloaded with ‘_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference) const [with _Tp = void(); __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = void (*)(); __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference = void (&)()]’
   96 |       address(const_reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      |       ^~~~~~~

How can I initialise and access this inline temporary vector without explicitly specifying the type, which would of course encode the function signature and return type?
Why am I doing this?
I have multiple single-integer-templated functions with distinct signatures and return-types:
template <int N> void  f(int x)        { ... }
template <int N> float g(int x, int y) { ... }
...

The template parameter informs compile-time optimisations in the functions (for more info, see this SO post). A simple way to choose the template parameter of the invoked function is to build an array of pointers to the function with all legal template parameters:
std::vector <void(*)(void)> f_funcs { f<0>, f<1>, f<2>, ... };

int param = 2;
f_funcs[param]();

Notice I explicitly specified the type void(*)(void) (the signature of f) as the vector template. I would have to hardcode the array initialisation for every one of my distinctly-typed functions:
std::vector <float(*)(int,int)> g_funcs { g<0>, g<1>, g<2>, ... };

int param = 2;
float ret = g_funcs[param](6,9);

This compiles fine, but is tedious boilerplate. I wish to avoid hardcoding an array literal of function pointers for each of my functions, especially because some of them accept two template parameters and need a 2D initialiser. So, I wrote a macro:
#define GET_FUNC(func, param) \
    (vector {func<0>, func<1>, func<2>, ...} ) [param]

int param = 3;
auto f_ = GET_FUNC(f, param);
auto g_ = GET_FUNC(g, param);

f_();
float x = g_(6,9);

Use of implicit typing avoids me having to pass the signatures of f and g to the macro. This compiles fine in Clang, but as described above, does not compile in GCC.
Introducing decltype...
#define GET_FUNC(func, param) \
    (vector <decltype(func<0>)> {func<0>, func<1>, func<2>, ...}) [param]

does not compile in Clang nor GCC.

"but fails in GCC.." Works here with all three compilers

This is a GCC bug (probably https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87709), fixed in GCC 12.

g++ c++17 class template argument deduction not working in a very specific case

@cpplearner ahh that's helpful to know, thanks very much! Is there a workaround for older compilers? My code is for a library which aims for wide (and old) compiler support

@AntiEarth No, asking for a mcve or suggesting to use latest version of compilers is not dogmatic. Also the post has no mcve. We can't copy/paste your snippet and reproduce the said issue/error. There are no #includes in the given post.

"You have not "suggested" to use the latest compiler version..." I literally said "always use latest version of compiler" and then provided the link to the dupe that reported the gcc bug mentioned above by cpplearner.

The workaround is already mentioned in the dupe. and it was also mentioned here.

Function decays to function pointer in some case, but if you use directly the right type, it is ok: (std::vector<decltype(&f)>{&f, &f, &f}) [0];. Demo

@AntiEarth Simpler workaround which was already mentioned. Just put one more parenthesis around like auto elem = ((std::vector{1, 2, 3}))[0];. Demo with gcc11.4

As commented by Jarod42, a workaround to support versions of GCC earlier than 12 is to maintain an array of explicit pointers:
(std::vector <decltype(&f)> {&f, &f, &f}) [0]

Despite the comments, this is not the (inapplicable) solution presented in this related but simpler problem. This question is not a duplicate (gee wizz)!
The solution presented by user12002570
does not work for the templated functions described in my question (godbolt).
// fails to compile in GCC < v12
auto func = ((vector {f<0>, f<1>, f<2>}))[0];

